# Cloudformation custom resources trigger

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

My goal is to write a Lambda function to attach a role to a EC2 instance based on tags. So whenever a new Ec2 instance is created, a role has to be attached to it automatically. I am looking to trigger a lambda function based on EC2 instance state change (running), and I also want to pass parameters of the IAM role to attch to EC2 for which I would have to use Custom Resources (IAM role creation is part of the same template).

Could someone help me with the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You question answer already contains the answer.

What you want to achieve can be done using [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

To develop a custom resources, AWS's [crhelper](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/custom-resource-helper) is very useful. It saves you from coding a lot of details that are needed for custom resources.